# Given 2 numpy 1-D sorted arrays, check for each element in A if there is an element in B such that abs(a-b) <= 10

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 1-D numpy sorted arrays, A and B. For each element in A, I want to check if there is an element in B such that

```
abs(a-b) <= 10
```

and keep only the elements that match the condition.
Is there a way to do it without loops?

The arrays are not necessarily of the same length, and the idx of the element that is closest to A in B could be far from the original idx in A. Otherwise I could use something like

```
A[(A >= B - 10) & (A <= B + 10)]
```

I don't mind using a lot of space, so I can create 2 new arrays of size B[-1] and use the elements in A,B as indices where there is 1 in the new arrays, but I can't think of a solution without loops that way either. Thought of using np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided, but not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
answer = a[np.sum(abs(a.reshape(a.shape[0], 1) - b) <= 10,axis=-1) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with broadcasting `B`

```
A[np.isclose(A, B[:, None], atol=10).any(0)]
```